# Remove temporary facts in Jess

Tags: java, protege, jess

I am trying to display all instance slot values and in the end remove it after all its bindings are processed through the following rule:

```
(defrule findSourcesOfPollution
    (object 
        (is-a http..#PollutionSources)              
        (OBJECT ?sitepoll)          
        (http..#potentialPollutant          
        $? ?b&:(eq (instance-name ?b)(instance-name http..#BiochemicalOxygenDemand)) $?) 
        (..#pollutionSourceName ?psName) 
        (http..#pollutionType ?psType) 
    )     
    (object 
        (is-a http..#MeasurementSite) 
        (OBJECT ?loc)
        (http..#hasSourcesOfPollution $? ?sitepoll $?)
    )
    (object 
            (is-a http..#tmpModerateMeasurement) 
            (OBJECT ?mob)
            (http..#observationResultLocation ?loc)
    )
=> 
    (printout t "pollution sources: " (instance-name ?sitepoll) " (Type: " ?psType ")" crlf)
    (unmake-instance ?mob)
)
```

But, the rule outputs only one pollution source, because the `unmake-instance` removes the instance and stops other bindings to be displayed.

EDIT:
Motivated by @laune comment I tried the following approach using `foreach` loop, but yet again not output is received:

```
(defrule findSourcesOfPollution 
    (object 
        (is-a http..#MeasurementSite) 
        (OBJECT ?loc)
        (http..#hasSourcesOfPollution $?sitepoll)
    )
    (object 
            (is-a http..#tmpModerateBODMeasurement) 
            (OBJECT ?mob)
            (http..#observationResultLocation ?loc)
    )
    (bind ?poll nil)
=> 
    (foreach ?poll ?sitepoll 
        (slot-get ?poll http..#potentialPollutant)
        (if(eq ?poll http..#BiochemicalOxygenDemand) then 
            (printout t "Pollution source: " (instance-name ?poll) " (Type: " ?loc ")" crlf)
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the list of sites to a list variable

```
(object 
    (is-a http..#MeasurementSite) 
    (OBJECT ?loc)
    (http..#hasSourcesOfPollution $?sitepoll )
)
```

and on the right hand side iterate the list:

```
(foreach ?site ?sitepoll (printout ...))
```

Comment: Yes, applying `foreach` helps, but not at all since `?sitepoll` should be filtered out to include only `BiochemicalOxygenDemand` sources of pollution (see the first object clause). I tried to transform the `?sitepoll` into a list i.e. `$?sitepoll` but no output is produced and it's expected because a list (`$?sitepoll` in MeasurementSite object) is not equal to a variable (`?sitepoll` in PollutionSources object)

Comment: I tried the foreach approach (see the EDIT section in the question text) but yet again no output is printed out and I think it's because of `?poll` variable which cannot be bound in the RHS.

Comment: Grrr, always the mistake of copying the variable including the effing dollar. Must have `?sitepoll` on the RHS. Edited.

Comment: Corrected it, but still cannot filter `?sitepoll` list to include only those of `BiochemicalOxygenDemand` sources of pollution :(

Comment: So it's only the filtering that does not work? Don't know what the multislot `http..#potentialPollutant` contains... Does `instance-name` really work on these values?

Comment: Yes, I need only to filter the list. The rule without the `(object (is-a http..#PollutionSources) ..(http..#pollutionType ?psType)` works well. It returns me the full list of potential sources of pollution which is filtered in the upper mentioned part. And yes the `instance-name` works on these values.

Comment: In the rule after "EDIT" you don't use `instance-name`, you do `(eq ?poll http..#BiochemicalOxygenDemand)` . Perhaps you omit the test and simply print the result of `instance-name` of everything that's in the list. Also, does `?sitepoll` have elements? - You'll have to exclude one possibility after the other. If necessary, apply Java methods, via the documented call-from-Jess technique.